# padding not working in span tag

Tags: html, css, padding

Ok, first off I want you all to know that I have tried using the `<span></span>` tag (though maybe incorrectly).

Is there something I'm doing wrong with the `<span></span>` tag? Or is there something I need to do differently altogether?

Here is my current code to create a space without `<br></br>`:

```css
#beforeImage span {
  padding: 40px;
}
```

```html
<span id="beforeImage">text</span>
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

2 things to fix:

- you were applying the CSS to `span` **of** an ID selector, but you were using a `span` **with** an ID selector in your HTML.
- `span` won't have `padding` because it is an inline element by default, so set `inline-block` or `block`

#### Snippet

```css
#beforeImage {
  padding: 40px;
  display: inline-block; /* or block */
 /* demo */
  background: red
 
}
```

```html
<span id="beforeImage">Foo bar</span>
```

Answer (score 3):

`<span>` is by default an `inline` element and will not be sized nor accept vertical padding without resetting its display to inline-block ( or else but inline).

You might look for:

```
span{
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 40px;
}
```

beside, `br` could still be used

```
 br {
  line-height:3em;
  vertical-align:top;/* debug FF/IE */
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GoVdYY

But, do you really need an extra tag, could you not apply a bottom margin or padding to another element ?

Comment: @KeeganBrown you need to clarify your question adding more about the situation, is there floats involved for instance ?

Answer (score 1):

Can simply target the Id of the span:

```
#beforeImage{
        display:inline-block;
        padding: 40px;
        }
```

Or all spans:

```
span{
display:inline-block;
padding: 40px;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't help though. I know I can do that, but I the actual <span></span> won't work

Comment: @Photo_Bomb you need to clarify your question adding more about the situation, is there floats involved for instance ?